# Firebase Analytics - app_open includes received push notifications

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

After integrating the Firebase Android SDK, and checking the Analytics section on the Firebase Console, it appears the `app_open` event is equivalent to app process creation (which also happens in the background when a push notification for this app is received).

Is there a way to measure the actual "app open" events (i.e. the user *launching* the app explicitly)?

Comment: Forgive me if this is the wrong place to ask this: I have run into the same problem and now I'm not sure how to handle it. If Firebase automatically logs app open events and I manually log them as well (say for example in my app's main function) using Firebase's predefined `FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logAppOpen()` function in Flutter, does this mean app open events are logged redundantly, thus invalidating my analyses? Or does Firebase automatically recognize that I'm manually logging these events? Would be glad to hear from your experience!

Answer (score 3):

You can manually log event on actual app open like

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("app_open", "app_open");
FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context);
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.LOGIN, bundle);
firebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks. When you say "on actual app open" - what do you mean? Where would you put that code, so that it only runs *once* when the user launches the app? Also, I think the `FirebaseAnalytics.Event.LOGIN` event should be used for actual "login" events. There is a predefined `APP_OPEN` event as well.